# How to move old chat data from Firebase database to another database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

We are developing a chat app for Android and iOS which uses a Firebase database for storing chat messages. We don't want keep all chat messages in Firebase database because storage gets bigger and expensive everyday. So we want to move 2 days old chat data to another database. Our purpose is to load new messages from Firebase storage and to load 2 days and older messages from another database when user wants to see older messages by scrolling up or pressing "load more" button.

Our database is like this:

Chat Room KEY

- Message Id
- Message
- Time and Date
- Reciever Id
- Sender Id

I have a few questions.

1. Can we automatically move older messages to another database based on message created date to decrease database storage costs? What is the best method for this? Do we need to use Firebase Functions?
2. Do we need to implement auth for our new database so that it know if our user wants to see data? Or is is it possible to query old message data from client side without authorizing our app users. Will it have security problems?
3. Which database we should use? How would you solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Exporting non-active data to another data source for archiving is definitely feasible. Have a look at the [Cloud Functions sample of limiting the number of children under a Firebase Database node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#other_database_sanitization_and_maintenance_use_cases) or alternatively at the [Cloud Functions sample of exporting data from the Firebase Database to BigQuery](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/bigquery-import).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but these examples shows deleting or limiting child nodes and it is only about moving data to BigQuery. We dont need to run code everytime a message is created. How should we change the code so that it runs once per a day or per two days and we need firebase to limit child number based on child create date not child count., So this way we will keep only childs they are not older than 2 days. This way we may keep maybe 10000 messages or maybe 10 so limiting children count is not feasable for us.

Comment: Are you proposing removing messages from a Firebase server and moving to another non-Firebase server to save money? The question states that *storage gets bigger and expensive everyday* when I would propose the opposite is true; storage capacity expands at less cost per megabyte every day. While I understand the question, the data has to go somewhere, and if it's a lot of data, it still has to be paid for. Also, you are greatly *increasing* your codebase complexity as now you support two different databases. Stick with Firebase - contact support for options and maybe a solution.

Comment: To periodically run Cloud Functions code, see this example: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron. I'm really just trying to give you starting points, because as it stands you question is incredibly broad and there are many possible solutions. Following on these starting points will allow you to narrow the scope of your question down.